# MultiThreading : Map Performance

Tags: java, multithreading

In multiThreading I want to use a map which will be updated, which Map will be better considering the performance 1. HashMap 2. ConcurrentHashMap? also, will it perform slow if i make it volatile?

It is going to be used in a Java batch for approx. 20Million records.
Currently i am not sharing this map among threads.
will sharing the map among threads reduce performance?

Comment: You should provide a bit more context. What will it actually be used for? How many reads/writes per second are you expecting? This is information that enables the community to give you much higher quality answers. Keep this in mind for future questions you ask.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. it is going to be used for java batch as i edited in the question, i don'y have data for read/write per second. This batch can run using 80/100 threads

Comment: To add more detail(from AWR report) as asked by @Sty                                                                                       Physical reads(blocks) : 60.9 per sec                                                                  Physical writes(blocks) : 1,358.1 per sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashMap will be better performance-wise, as it is not synchronized in any way. `ConcurrentHashMap` adds overhead to manage concurrent read and - especially - concurrent write access.

That being said, in a multithreaded environment, you are responsible for synchronizing access to `HashMap` as needed, which will cost performance, too.

Therefore, I would go for `HashMap` only if the use case allows for very specific optimization of the synchronization logic. Otherwise, ConcurrentHashMap will save you a lot of time working out the synchronization.

However, please note that even with `ConcurrentHashMap` you will need to carefully consider what level of synchronization you need. ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, but not fully synchronized. For instance, if you absolutely need to synchronize each read access with each write access, you will still need custom logic, since for a read operation `ConcurrentHashMap` will provide the state after the last successfully finished write operation. That is, there might still be an ongoing write operation which will not be seen by the read.

As for volatile, this only ensures that changes to that particular field will be synchronized between threads. Since you will likely not change the reference to the `HashMap` / `ConcurrentHashMap`, but work on the instance, the performance overhead will be negligible.